# Designing a diode waveform shaping circuit resulting in specific transfer function

Tags: diodes, transfer-function, zener

[image: Transfer Function]

Below is the circuit I built, yet the solution has the resistor as a load resistor instead of as a current limiting resistor. I am wondering if this circuit will output this transfer function.

[image: circuit]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there... The diode network you came up with makes sense.

However, your circuit will clamp the output voltage at +0.7 and -4.7V instead of presenting a transfer function with slope=1 as requested.

Consider having the diode network in series between Vi and Vo instead. It's a good idea to have a shunt resistor on the output side to make sure Vo goes to zero between -4.7V and +0.7V.

Answer (score 4):

Just in case it helps (and because you already have selected an answer, so no harm no foul), something like this is what was suggested I think:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhYRWA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A Spice simulation shows:

[image]